# How do I reference an already created handson table to alter it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, handsontable

I'm making a screen with `1 to n` hansontables added dinamically depending of other entities in database. Each table will have <kbd>save</kbd>, <kbd>x</kbd> (remove lines) and <kbd>+</kbd> (add lines) buttons.

I succesfully created various tables, like in the handsontable examples with global variables like:

```
var hot;

$(document).ready(function () {

  var container = document.getElementById('basic_example');
  hot = new Handsontable(container, config);
}
```

Then in other methods I can alter the table like:

```
function addRow() {
    hot.alter("insert_row");
}
```

But, as long as my number of tables is not fixed I need to create the tables and after reference the objects and modify them.

But all handsontable documentation ([`1`](https://github.com/handsontable/handsontable/wiki/Methods) [`2`](http://docs.handsontable.com/0.15.0-beta6/Core.html#alter)) is based on creating a table with `hot = new Handsontable(container, config);` and after referencing this variable i.e. `hot.getData()`

So, my question is **which is the correct way to reference an already created `handson` table??**

I've tried several things:

- Using `JQuery` like

  ```
   $('idOfTheTable')
  ```

  or

  ```
  var hot = new Handsontable(document.getElementById('idOfTheTable'));
  hot.alter('insert_row', 10);
  ```
- Creating a `DOM` function `$$` like:

  ```
  var $$ = function(id) {
      return document.getElementById(id);
  };

  $$(idOfTheTable);
  ```
- [Check here a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9L9ws9gp/) with my last try:

  ```
  var $container = $("#" + tableName);
  var handsontable = $container.data('handsontable');
  handsontable.alter('insert_row');
  ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer,** speaking with a friend he gave me the clue to solve it. I used same technique I use to keep google markers and reference the tooltips. Keep references into an `array`.

---

## OWN LONG ANSWER

Actually I cannot reference via JQuery even following the [JQuery guide](http://docs.handsontable.com/0.18.0/demo-jquery.html) of Handsontable documentation. But as long as the reference exists in some moment, I can keep this reference in an array declared as global variable.

```
tables = [];
```

Each time I call method that creates a table I push the table reference into the array to mantain it alive.

```
var hot = new Handsontable(container, options);
tables.push(hot);
```

Done this, how do I know which table I must call? Simple, the HTML code is also created dynamically by a `<c:forEach items="${list}" var="item">` I just create a counter that is incremented in each iteration. I just create table witch `id="table_{counter}"` and get position with

```
var tablePosition = parseInt(tableName.split("_")[1]);
```

---

## HOT TEAM LONG ANSWER

*First of all: many thanks [Aleksandra and Handsontable team](http://handsontable.com/contact-us.html) for the fast, great and quick support*.

> The key is used to better track your instances and you can choose to write it down with an object that will easily let you manage Handsontable instances.

Find [here the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qjws6qfy/) demo.

Important parts, define a `HotRegisterer` that will keep track of created tables:

```
var HotRegisterer = {
    bucket: {},
    register: function(key, container, options) {
        var hot = new Handsontable(container, options);
        
        if (typeof key === 'string') {
            this.bucket[key] = hot;    
        } else if (typeof key === 'object') {
            key['__hot'] = hot;
        }
    },
    getInstance: function(key) {
        var hot;
        
        if (typeof key === 'string') {
            hot = this.bucket[key];    
        } else if (typeof key === 'object') {
            hot = key['__hot'];
        }
        
        return hot;
    }
};
```

Then, having this object, you create tables like:

```
var container = document.getElementById('example1');
  
HotRegisterer.register('myhot', container, {
    data: getCarData(),
    colHeaders: true
});
```

And you alter tables like:

```
HotRegisterer.getInstance('myhot').getSourceDataAtCol(0);
```

Far away more elegant and clean than my sollution.

Comment: Yeah the `HotRegisterer` solution is great. Also if you wanted to still use yours, I would recommend a map instead of an array. That way you can use ids to track them.

Comment: How to use it in a angularjs project? I can't find any (full) demos. just snippets.

Comment: @ThorstenC contact with HandsOnTable team, they give to me a super fast, professional and clean answer. https://handsontable.com/contact.html

Comment: Hello,

`HotRegisterer.getInstance('myhot')` is providing me the instance and i am also able to access its properties. But `search` property is not accessible.
Can anyone tell me the reason?

Answer (score 0):

You can provide similar solution with minimum code as follows:

```
//References to handsontable objects on Tab. Key=TabId, Value=Reference to Variable
var tabHandsOnTable = {};
```

To display data in handsontable inside container in a Tab (variable ***liTabId*** is current TabId) following is the code:

```
    //Displaying Cuboid in HandsonTable
  var container = document.getElementById(divCuboidWB);
  var hot = new Handsontable(container, {
    data: lidata.liarray,
    colHeaders : liHdr.liHdrArray,
    renderAllRows: true,
    rowHeaders: true,
    minSpareRows: 1,
  });
  //Saving reference of handsontable in global objects. key=liTabId
  tabHandsOnTable[liTabId] = hot;
```

Now you can access the handsontable from ***tabHandsOnTable{}*** using ***activeTabId*** which is tab id of current tab. Further the cell of handosontable is updated using ***setDateAtCell*** function as shown below:

```
//Render handsontable cell
function renderCell(rowid, colid, string_value, formula_string, cell_access)
{
  tabHandsOnTable[activeTabId].setDataAtCell(rowid, colid, string_value);
}
```

This is working example, and i can display multiple Tables in same browser window.